# Where to set the contentView of UISearchDisplayController that was made in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, ipad

I have a UISearchBar in a UIToolbar that has a UISearchDisplayController tied to it. I would like the UISearchDisplayController's results to show in a popover below the UISearchBar but I'm having trouble with this. I'm pretty sure it's because there is not a contentsController set but I can't find where to assign a contentsController to a UISearchDisplayController that was created in Interface Builder. I've tried making it programatically and calling the initwithsearchbar: andcontentscontroller: but I think that will only work if the search bar and controller are created programatically which I don't want to do, any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UISearchDisplayController` is made to *only* be used with another `UIViewController` (`contentsController`, as you mentioned).  Though it can be used with **any** `UIViewController`, it's main use (and least painful use) is intended to be with a `UITableViewController`.

The `contentsController` is supposed to be "responsible for managing the original content to be searched".  If the controller is not managing a collection of items, there's nothing to search.  `UITableView` is the main standard controller that's managing multiple items.

If your `UISearchBar` is in a `UIToolbar`, the toolbar is likely in a main view that's managed by a `UIViewController`.  If you programmatically access the readonly `contentsController` value at runtime, that's what i'd expect you to find.

Xcode4 (and likely InterfaceBuilder) creates a lot of connections when you just drop that search controller into the nib.  They're now pointing at that `UIViewController` (the File's Owner?) and expecting it to implement some of the entirely optional methods in `UISearchBarDelegate` and `UISearchDisplayDelegate` protocols.

You likely want to implement

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
    textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
  // called when text changes (including clear)
  NSLog(@"[%@ %@]", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}
```

on the mystery `contentsController` and perform the winnowing each time text is typed?

(good luck)

I suspect you may not want the `UISearchDisplayController` in the mix at all for this one.